# squeryl enum as string but not as ints

Tags: scala, lift, squeryl

I have an enum type

```scala
object UserState extends Enumeration {
  type UserState = Value
  val unconfirmed = Value("unconfirmed")
  val locked = Value("locked")
  val active = Value("active")
}

class User {
  val state: UserState.Value
}
```

And try to execute query

```scala
from(MySchema.users)
  (u => where(u.state === UserState.unconfirmed) select(u))
  .headOption
```

But the resulting sql have something like `users.state = 0` instead of `users.state = 'unconfirmed'`. How to have squeryl treat enum as string rather then int?

And also this is a lift-based application. And I try to use EnumFeild of squeryl-record. May be there a lift-based desigion does exist?

Comment: As far as I know, squeryl can't do this automatically. Here's a thread on the squeryl mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/squeryl/enumeration$20string/squeryl/u2NTd06DFUI/oR8tQqEOk-wJ

Comment: thanks for the link, but looks like it doesnt work. I'll search later (in case they dont have auto way, I dont need it. I just use workaround like `UserState.unconfirmed.toString`)